# Is there a way to prevent Visual Studio from printing Thread exited statements into the Output Window?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Such as:

`The thread '<No Name>' (0x16b4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).`

When I am using the Output Window for my own data, the threading messages clutters it.

Comment: There are so many alternative ways to log data, why use the Output Window?

Comment: It's just for quick and dirty projects that I don't want to spend too much time.

Comment: I find it useful to use the debug output this way because it persists out of the debug session easing reference during development, and isn't obnoxious like having a log file open.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Yes, this is easy to do.  Just right-click the Output window and untick the "Thread Exit Messages" option:

[image]

If you want the setting to apply to every future project instead of just the current one then use Tools > Options > Debugging > Output Window > Thread Exit Messages = Off.

Comment: Also out of curiosity, is this a project setting or a global VS setting? Just curious.

Comment: Tools + Options, Debugging, Output Window settings.

Comment: Why did it take me ten years to try to google this. Ugh! Thx!