# Is there a way to prevent Visual Studio from printing Thread started and finished statements into the Output Window?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have a lot of

```
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #49
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #49
```

in the console and it's hard to use the console when I want to print something for debug. Is there anyway to remove these statements from the Output Window?

My question is really similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19199742/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-visual-studio-from-printing-thread-exited-statements-i). The solution works to remove the exited statements, but it doesn't remove the started and finished statements

**EDIT**
It is only occurring with a Xamarin iOS project

Comment: That is not a normal notification, threadpool starts and stops are not logged by the debugger.  An add-in doing this is a possibility, they are easy to disable so start there first.

Comment: It is because of Xamarin

Comment: Have you found a solution for this yet?

Answer (score 1):

Although not a real solution, this is how I managed to organize my Output window:

Go to `Tools` > `Options` > `Extensions and Updates` and look for an extension called `VSColorOutput` by [Mike Ward](https://mike-ward.net/vscoloroutput/).
*(Disclaimer: I am not the author, or related to him in any way.)*

You might want to fine-tune the colors to your taste and add additional Regex filter criterias.

This is how it looks on my end. I colored the Xamarin noise in a dark gray and my own messages in green. Makes it way easier to scan the Output window for important stuff.

[image: Example Output window with colored messages]

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to write how you got your output to the console. If you use a System.Diagnostics.TraceListener object for it, via Debug.Listeners.Add or something similar, you can use the property TraceListener.TraceOptions.

MSDN says:

> Traceoptions specifies trace data options to be written to the trace output.

Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a10k7w6c(v=vs.110).aspx

and

[An easy way to get common and useful data in Traces(click to view)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2006/08/01/684500.aspx)

Comment: I did not put those output to the console. That is my problem. And I want to remove them

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're looking for this one :

Right click on the Output window for the Debug selection and select which types of messages to see.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaB1k.png)

Comment: As they said they have removed thread exit messages, but thread started and thread finished aren't filterable this way