# Filter out thread exited events from Visual Studio Diagnostic Tools

Tags: visual-studio-2015, intellitrace, diagnostic-tools

The Diagnostic Tools window by default includes IntelliTrace events like these:

> **Program Output:** The thread 0x16b4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

For applications with many threads, this can be a lot of clutter. It's easy enough to [filter these from the Output window](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19199742/145173). How about the Diagnostic Tools window?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use *Filter* function that is available in the toolbar of *Events* tab. Click it, find *Program Output* item on the list and uncheck a check box next to it.

[image]

Comment: That would throw out the baby with the bathwater. I want to keep program output in general. I just want to filter out the thread exit events.