# Prevent a Console App (.NET Core) from printing "exited with code 0." in VS2019 and VS2022

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

When I start a Console App (.NET Core) with Ctrl+F5 (Start Without Debugging) in Visual Studio Community 2019 (Version 16.3.1), the following message is appended in the Console window at the end:

> C:\HelloWorld\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\HelloWorld.exe (process 1672) exited with code 0.

```
using System;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Console output]

Is there any way to prevent Visual Studio 2019 from printing this message? I tried the solution from [preventing a similar message from appearing in the Output Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19199742/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-visual-studio-from-printing-thread-exited-statements-i), by changing the option: Tools > Options > Debugging > Output Window > Process Exit Messages = Off, but it has no effect in the Console Window.

[image: Visual Studio Options]

Note: this message is not shown in Visual Studio 2017. It is only shown in Visual Studio 2019, and only on .NET Core apps.

**Note 2022:** the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58227821/11178549) is not working on Visual Studio 2022 version 17.4.0 (the latest version).

Comment: Its the community spirit. Anyway this might be a bug

Comment: If you are sure that this happens even on a freshly installed instance of Visual Studio 2019, I would create an issue over on the forum. You can do this by hitting `Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem`

Comment: @Twenty I updated the Visual Studio with the latest version a few days ago. I don't remember if it was the same before the update, because I was working with VS 2017. I am not sure if it's a problem or a feature. It may be configurable somewhere in the Options.

Comment: Why is this a problem? Ctrl-F5 is for testing (and knowing the exit code is helpful feedback when it is significant). Any real use of a console app wouldn't be from within VS.

Comment: @Richard during development I press frequently Ctrl-F5 to test my app, and the AppPath/ProcessId/ExitCode message is zero value information that steals my attention from what I really want to see. If my application makes use of the exit code (rarely does), I could print it myself.

Comment: For VS2019 this is feature, not a bug.  It addresses a 28 year old complaint from programmers that write small console mode apps, they always forgot to add "Press any key to continue" code or setting a breakpoint at the end of main.  So they couldn't read the output of their program, many many questions about it at SO and the forums.  In VS2019 the console window no longer closes.  And dutifully reports that the program ended.  This is a pure debugger feature, you won't see this when you run the program normally.

Comment: @HansPassant the "Press any key to continue" message was always there for Ctrl+F5 (personal experience from VS2008, VS2017, VS2019). I don't mind that, it is helpful. What annoys me is the long exit-code message that is printed before the press-to-continue message.

Comment: Could I ask why this is a problem, out of interest?

Comment: @KierenJohnstone it's a little annoyance I would happily live without. :-)

Comment: I don't know if this will be possible without a VS setting. `Console` exposes it output stream through [Console.Out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.out) and a setter through `Console.SetOut`, but those extra lines are written to stdout directly. So we don't have a way to intercept them.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can disable it by checking the `Tools > Options > Debugging > General > Automatically close the console when debugging stops` option:

[image: Visual Studio 2019 Options]

As stated by the console itself (Visual Studio 2019 v16.3.2):

[image: Console App]

That will make the console just print `Press any key to continue...` by starting without debugging (`CTRL` + `F5`) and not the exit code (still leaves the console open):

[image: No exit code]

Comment: Ahhh! Nice find Ivan! Thank you so much! 

Comment: I just installed the Visual Studio 2022 version 17.4.0, the version that supports the new .NET 7, and the above configuration no longer prevents the *"exited with code 0."* message from appearing in the Console (without debugging). :-( [Screenshot](https://prnt.sc/nEZFuHbBM4j1).