# How to hide path/exit code message in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to hide that exit code message that appears in console before "Press Any key to close this window..." on VS community 2022.

[image: Picture]

I tried the accepted answer on [this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58179185/prevent-a-console-app-net-core-from-printing-exited-with-code-0-in-vs2019), but didn't work, as shown in the picture. I also tried to turn off all output messages from [Tools->Options->Debugging->Output Window] and didn't work.

Is there anyway to hide/remove that message?

Comment: Press Ctrl+F5 to run without the debugger.

Comment: That's what I'm actually using.